# MyApp.app.getController(‘controller name’) method throws an error (c.getModuleClassName is not a function in ext-all-rtl-debug.js file )

Tags: extjs

I used MyApp.app.getController method to get the instance of the controller. But it throws the error c.getModuleClassName is not a function !!!
I have added controller in app.JS file too !!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without more details, like maybe the code in question, it is highly unlikely that anybody can tell you why you might get this error. Consider adding the code and a more detailed version of the error message.

Comment: @Kabilan Nakkeeran provide your code, where are you calling that method? in view? or other components controller?

Comment: @LightNight Sorry to not respond !! I got it !!